# maximum possible value of $g(x)$

Tags: calculus

> If function $g(x)$ is continuous and differentiable in $[2,14]$ such that $g(20)=-5$. If $g'(x)\leq 10$. Then largest possible value of $g(14)$ is

What i try

$$g'(x)\leq 10$$

$\displaystyle\int^{20}_{14}g'(x)dx \leq \int^{20}_{14}10dx$

$g(20)-g(14)\leq 10(20-14)=60$

$g(14)\geq 60-g(20)=60+5=65$

But i did not understand How can i findcmaximum of $g(14)$. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this wasn't supposed to be $g(2) = -5$? because you only know that $g$ is con. and diff. in $[2,14]$ not $[14,20]$.

Comment: What does the range $[2,14]$ have to do with anything?

Comment: We don't know if $g$ is differentiable at $x=20$. Replace $g(20)=-5$ with $g(2)=-5$ and integrate from $2$ to $14$. The last inequality would be $g(14)\le 65$.

Comment: Thanks so much to all. Yes all are right there is a printing mistake actually it is $f(2)$ instead of $f(20)$